# Get API Response from src inside iFrame

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-maps, iframe, jsx

I have an iframe which uses google streetview api:

```
export default function GoogleMapDrawer(props: any): ReactElement {
    const streetView = `${google}?key=${key}&location=${props.location}`;

return(
        <Drawer
            <iframe
                allowFullScreen
                height='100%'
                loading='lazy'
                src={streetView}
                style={{border: 0}}
                width='100%' />
        </Drawer>
)};
```

In some cases the latitude, longitude provided into the src URL are invalid for google and the network response will be "Search returned no images". I want to be able to detect what the response is from google and provide an alternate map/preform another action. How can I read the response from src?

Comment: this isn't possible. The parent page can't obtain any information whatsoever from the contents of an iframe pointing at another origin that isn't allowing such interaction.

Answer (score 0):

```
export default function GoogleMapDrawer(props: any): ReactElement {
    const streetView = `${google}?key=${key}&location=${props.location}`;
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview/metadata?key=${key}&location=${props.location}`)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(
                (result) => {
                    setIsLoaded(true);
                    setShowSpinner(false)
                    setItems(result);
                    console.log(result)
                },
                (error) => {
                    setIsLoaded(true);
                    setShowSpinner(false)
                    setError(error);
                }
            );
    }, [props.location]);


return(
        <Drawer
            <iframe
                allowFullScreen
                height='100%'
                loading='lazy'
                src={streetView}
                style={{border: 0}}
                width='100%' />
        </Drawer>
)};
```

Response is saved in 'items' and can be leveraged accordingly.